# How Can I Disable Automatic Lock/Log-Off on Disconnect for a Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-access, remote-desktop

So recently I purchased a Windows VPS (Windows Server 2012 R2) from the site http://RunAbove.com. I purchased it because I want a program to be always running on it, much like a server. The only problem I have is that whenever I disconnect my Remote Desktop Connection, the server automatically locks. As a result, the program is suspended and doesn't function like it should. So my question is, how can I disable automatic lock/log-off on disconnect?

I have tried many "solutions" that I found online, but none of them seem to fix my issue. I have modified the group policy and setting the idle disconnect time to a high number, but that didn't work. I have also tried to disable the lock screen through gpedit.msc, but that also did not seem to work.

If anyone has a solution, I will be greatly appreciative. I have been trying to figure this out for the past 2 days with no luck.

Comment: That's just how Remote Desktop works.  There is no way to leave the server unlocked after disconnecting from the Remote Desktop session.  You should fix whatever it is about your program that stops it from functioning normally when the server is locked.

Comment: I have definitely used a VPS that stayed logged in even when the Remote Desktop app is closed. In fact, at http://vps9.net, it allowed me to stay logged in (not locked) when I closed the Remote Desktop Session. In that case, my server was able to run 24/7 without any inhibitions. This server at http://RunAbove.com is also a windows VPS, but it keeps locking whenever I disconnect. There has to be a way to disable that.

Comment: vps9 *might* have hacked Windows to behave differently, I suppose, though it seems very unlikely.  But when you say it wasn't locked ... how could you tell?  From a quick glance at their web site, vps9 doesn't seem to offer console access, only RDP access.  (Another possibility is that they used RDP-to-console rather than the RDP support built into Windows.)

Comment: Well when I connected to my VPS9 server, I did not see the login screen/lock screen when I connected. With the RunAbove server, when I connect, it shows lock screen briefly before unlocking/re-logging in. Logically, I just assumed that VPS9 didn't lock the server while RunAbove does. I may be totally wrong. Also, the server I had running on the VPS9 server didn't seem to be suspended when I disconnected

Comment: Windows doesn't suspend applications when the server is locked.  Have you checked whether your application works on a desktop machine when it is locked?  (The problem might be something completely different.)

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic, since the programming aspect of the question is tangential and the OP doesn't appear to be interested in it.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you.

1. Create new user (in VPS) on control panel.
2. Open the "Remote Desktop" in VPS then connect to 127.0.0.1
3. Use the username and password you created in 1st step.
4. Then run your program in VPS > remote desktop.

With this, your program will continue to run even if you disconnect on VPS.

Comment: any success with this?